# inserir valor em uma requisição de dados Json

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

preciso escrever uma função que acesse um campo especifico dentro de um arquivo Json. Os campos do Json estão listados como id1, id2, id3... e o valor a ser acessado será passado pela própria função. A minha questão fica mais clara observando o código a seguir:

Javascript

```js
function myFunction (x) {
    fetch ('dados.json')
    .then(function(response){
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(data){
        console.log("data.id" + x)
    })
}
```

Json

```js
{
    "id1":{
            "nome": "João",
            "sobrenome": "Medeiros"
          },
    "id2":{
            "nome": "Mário",
            "sobrenome": "Freitas"
          },
    "id3":{
            "nome": "Joana",
            "sobrenome": "Cunha"
          },
```

No código acima o valor retornado no console é uma string, como eu faço para retornar o campo correspondente ao valor fornecido por X.

Desde já, agradeço.

Comment: Veja se é isso: `console.log(data["id"+x])`

Comment: Funcionou. Valeu!

Answer (score 1):

`id1` é o nome de uma propriedade do objeto expresso em `dados.json`. Assim sendo você pode acessar seu valor via *[bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation)*, ou *notação em colchetes*:

```
function myFunction (x) {
    fetch ('dados.json')
    .then(function(response){
        var data = response.json();
        var valor = data['id' + x];
        console.log(valor);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Acesse como se fosse um índice:

```js
var x = { 
    "id1": {
            "nome": "João",
            "sobrenome": "Medeiros"
          },
    "id2":{
            "nome": "Mário",
            "sobrenome": "Freitas"
          },
    "id3":{
            "nome": "Joana",
            "sobrenome": "Cunha"
          }
        };

var num=1

console.log(x["id"+num].nome);
```